# html select dropdown wont stay selected

Tags: html, select

I have a select dropdown list on my website(www.irishbonus.comule.com/en/). However when I select an option from the dropdown list and press submit I would like that the option stay selected.
Here is the code for the select:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<strong>   Select Subject:</strong>
<select name="formSubject" class="dropdown">
  <option value=">>>">">>>"</option>
  <option value="Accounting">Accounting</option>
  <option value="Agricultural Science">Agricultural Science</option>
  <option value="Agricultural Economics">Agricultural Economics</option>
  <option value="Applied Mathematics">Applied Mathematics</option>
  <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>
  <option value="Art (jc only)">Art (jc only)</option>
  <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
  <option value="Business (jc only)">Business (jc only)</option>
  <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
  <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
  <option value="Civic (jc only)">Civic (jc only)</option>
  <option value="Classical Studies">Classical Studies</option>
  <option value="Construction Studies">Construction Studies</option>

//more options

  <option value="Typewriting (jc only)">Typewriting (jc only)</option>
</select>

<table width="300px">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<strong>Insert Mark:</strong>
<input type="text" name="formMark" maxlength="2" size="4" value="<?=$mark;?>"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a server-side language for this. You already seem to be using PHP so just add some PHP code to do it. The best solution would be storing your options inside an array and then iterating over the array, outputting the `<option>` tags and adding the `selected` attribute if the value matches the submitted value.

```
<select name="formSubject" class="dropdown">
<?php
$options = ['Accounting', 'Agricultural Science', '...'];
$selected = isset($_POST['formSubject']) ? $_POST['formSubject'] : '';
foreach($options as $option) {
    echo '<option value="'.$option.'"'.($selected == $option ? ' selected' : '').'>'.$option.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: so I just put my options in the option array and this could work?

Comment: I tried putting that in(with the options) instead of the old select menu and im getting a parse error :/

Answer (score 0):

He forgot the array(), that is why the parse error is there

here:

```
<select name="formSubject" class="dropdown">
<?php
$options = array('Accounting', 'Agricultural Science', '...');
$selected = isset($_POST['formSubject']) ? $_POST['formSubject'] : '';
foreach($options as $option) {
    echo '<option value="'.$option.'"'.($selected == $option ? ' selected' : '').'>'.$option.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: I got it working eventually: <option value="Accounting (lc only)"<?php echo (input_value('formSubject') == 'Accounting (lc only)') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Accounting (lc only)</option>

Comment: function input_value($x){
    if (isset($_POST[$x])) {
        return $_POST[$x];
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $selected = "";
    if(isset($_GET['spec'])) {
        if($_GET['spec'] == $row['id']) {
            $selected = "selected='selected'";
        }
    }
    print "<option ". $selected ." value='". $row['id'] ."'>". $row['ime']. "</option>";
}

$result->free();
```